# Fortran's do-loop over arbitary indices like for-loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, fortran

I have two p-times-n arrays `x` and `missx`, where `x` contains arbitrary numbers and `missx` is an array containing zeros and ones. I need to perform recursive calculations on those points where `missx` is zero. The obvious solution would be like this:

```
do i = 1, n
   do j = 1, p
      if(missx(j,i)==0) then
         z(j,i) = ... something depending on the previous computations and x(j,i)
      end if
   end do
end do
```

Problem with this approach is that most of the time `missx` is always 0, so there is quite a lot `if` statements which are always true.

In R, I would do it like this:

```
for(i in 1:n)
  for(j in which(xmiss[,i]==0))
     z[j,i] <- ... something depending on the previous computations and x[j,i]
```

Is there a way to do the inner loop like that in Fortran? I did try a version like this:

```
do i = 1, n
   do j = 1, xlength(i) !xlength(i) gives the number of zero-elements in x(,i)
     j2=whichx(j,i) !whichx(1:xlength(i),i) contains the indices of zero-elements in x(,i)
     z(j2,i) = ... something depending on the previous computations and x(j,i)
   end do
end do
```

This seemed slightly faster than the first solution (if not counting the amount of defining `xlength` and `whichx`), but is there some more clever way to this like the R version, so I wouldn't need to store those `xlength` and `whichx` arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you are going to get dramatic speedup anyway, if you must do the iteration for most items, than storing just the list of those with the 0 value for the whole array  is not an option. You can of course use the `WHERE` or `FORALL` construct.

```
forall(i = 1: n,j = 1: p,miss(j,i)==0) z(j,i) = ...
```

or just

```
where(miss==0) z = ..
```

But the ussual limitations of these constructs apply.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that where construct.