# Selecting a subset of an array given logical vector in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, logical-operators

In Fortran, is it possible to select certain parts of the an array by using some vector of logical values instead of the indices? For example like this:

```
iszero(1) = 0
iszero(2) = 1
iszero(3) = 0
sum0 = sum(iszero) !was  sum0 = sum(iszero==0)
!mymatrix is arbitary is 3 times 3 array
mysubmatrix(1:sum0,1:sum0) = mymatrix(iszero==0,iszero==0)
call dtrmv('l','n','u',sum0,mysubmatrix(1:sum0,1:sum0),sum0,x(1:sum0)),1)
```

If this is not possible directly, is there an easy (fast) way to find the indices where iszero=0?

edit: I changed the example to present a more realistic case, in previous case I just changed some values to 100.0d0, where the elementwise handling would have been ok..

edit2: had one type on the fourth row of the code

Comment: If it's any help, this question is related to the question I presented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773872/fortrans-do-loop-over-arbitary-indices-like-for-loop-in-r

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
where (mymatrix==0) mymatrix = 100.0d0
```

will set all elements in mymatrix which are 0 to 100.  If you are actually trying to do something a little more sophisticated than that, perhaps setting a matrix to have a 'checkerboard' of 1s and 0s you could try something like;

```
mymatrix(1:m:2,2:n:2) = 100d0
```

where m,n are the numbers of rows and columns in mymatrix.  I haven't tested this latter snippet, it's just a suggestion to consider array subscript triplets sometimes.

**EDIT**

If you actually want to use one matrix (or vector) as the mask in the where statement and another in the assignment part, ie something like this:

```
where(index_matrix==0) mymatrix = 100d0
```

then you have (I think) to ensure that `index_matrix` has the same size as `mymatrix`.  In your case you might end up with a statement such as:

```
where(reshape([0,1],[3,3],pad=[0,1])==0) mymatrix = 100d0
```

again I haven't tested this and I don't expect that I've got the padded reshape quite right but you can probably figure out the details.

**FURTHER EDIT**

I'm now finding it difficult to follow the question.  The statement

```
sum0 = sum(iszero==0)
```

will assign the value 1 to sum, so the statement

```
mysubmatrix(1:sum0,1:sum0) = mymatrix(iszero==0,iszero==0)
```

will, at run time, be something like this:

```
mysubmatrix(1:1,1:1) = mymatrix(iszero==0,iszero==0)
```

and I'm not sure that the rhs and lhs conform properly for Fortran.  Does this compile   ?  If it does, does it execute correctly (with array-bounds checking) ?

Are you trying to create `submatrix` which holds only the 0 elements of `mymatrix` ?  If so then I think you are going to have a hard time of it, for the general case.  Unless you can define the locations of the elements you want to select in terms of either indices or a vector of subscripts or a subscript triplet, then I don't see that you can make an array on the lhs from the array on the rhs.

If the locations of the 0s are arbitrary then you might be able to do what you want by flattening the original array to rank-1 and creating a rank-1 subarray of that, but you would lose the correspondence between 2D locations and their 1D counterparts.

**FINALLY**

Don't forget that you can, in Fortran 2003, use a pointer to refer to a sub-matrix defined by vector or triplet subscripts, for example

```
pointer_to_array => target_array(1:10:2,2:10:2)
```

and then pass `pointer_to_array` around.

Comment: I make no claims as to the relative performance of the whole-array operations and where statements against nested loops; sometimes the array syntax allows a clearer expression of the programmer's ideas and that is often more important than pure execution speed.

Comment: Sorry, my first example was bit too simplistic, but this is a good advice anyway. Thanks.

Comment: You're right, there was error on the fourth row of the code. And the row mysubmatrix(1:sum0,1:sum0) = mymatrix(iszero==0,iszero==0) does not compile, that's the problem ;) That was just an example how I would like it to work, in order to select that submatrix of zeros, just as you though. It seems clear now that it's is not possible to do in general case, so I'll think I do the initial checking on R where I can easily make the ncessary arrays of indices. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

For rank-1 array, the array subset can be taken by a local array mask using the intrinsic function `PACK`. For example (in Fortran 2003)

```
INTEGER :: X(5) = [1,2,0,3,0]
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: XX(:)
XX = PACK(X,X/=0)
```

will pick out the non-zero elements from X, and store into XX (on return XX = [1,2,3]).

Comment: @IRO-bot In fortran 2003, XX will be auto-allocated, hence no segfault.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is no, you cannot do what you are suggesting; at least upto FORTRAN 90 anyway. Having said that, I am not sure why something like

```
DO I = 1, 3
    DO J = 1, 3
        IF (iszero(I) == 0 .AND. iszero(J) == 0)
            mymatrix(I, J) = 100.0d0
        ENDIF
    ENDDO
ENDDO
```

Something like this for a 3x3 array would be rapid! Even if you had a large number of these DO loops it would still be relatively fast (faster than doing it than any other language at least!).

Comment: This would be good option for my example, but as I said at the end of my question (I should have emphazised it more), in real case I'm also doing something like call dtrmv('l','n','u',sum(iszero==0),mymatrix2(1:sum(iszero==0),1:sum(iszero==0)),sum(iszero==0),yhelp(1:sum(iszero==0)),1) ie. some matrix operations where the elementwise handling isn't an option

Comment: I see, sorry. @High Performance Mark's answer in this case looks reasonable. Good luck with it, all the best...